# Correlations for convection coefficients in tubes at high Reynolds numbers

Tags: heat-transfer, convection

I am looking for a correlation to calculate the heat transfer coefficient for a convection problem for turbulent flow in a tube at high Reynolds numbers of > 5×10<sup>6</sup>. This is where the Gnielinski correlation's suitable range ends. Are there any other correlations for higher Reynolds numbers? What error should I expect if I continue to use Gnielinski?

Comment: What do books like Simonson: Heat Transfer suggest?

Comment: That would be $Nu = 0.027\, (Re)^{0.8} \, (Pr)^{1/3} \, (\frac{\mu}{\mu_{wall}})^{0.14}$ for $0.7 < Pr < 16700$. I've never seen that one before though. It just says for fully developed flow at $Re < 10000$. Seems as it is more concerned with a good fit for low Reynolds numbers.